# Unable to load bitmap using Glide v4

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I am using Glide v4 to load a bitmap that can then be used to as a marker on the map. When I use the deprecated `SimpleTarget` like so everything works fine.

```
GlideApp.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(url)
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

            // load bitmap as marker
        }
    });
```

When I try removing the deprecated code and using `Target<Bitmap>` like given below I can see the `onLoadStarted` gets called but the `onResourceReady` is never called neither is the `onLoadFailed`.

```
GlideApp.with(getContext()).asBitmap()
    .load(UrlHelper.createUrl(poi.getMapMarker()))
    .into(marketBitmap);

private Target<Bitmap> marketBitmap = new Target<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadStarted(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
        Log.d("GlideMar", "marker load started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.e("GlideMar", "marker load failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
        Log.d("GlideMar", "onResourceReady");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
        Log.d("GlideMar", "marker onLoadCleared");
    }

    @Override
    public void getSize(@NonNull SizeReadyCallback cb) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeCallback(@NonNull SizeReadyCallback cb) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setRequest(@Nullable Request request) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Request getRequest() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d("GlideMar", "marker onStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.d("GlideMar", "marker onStop");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("GlideMar", "marker onDestroy");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Glide Custom Targets](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html#custom-targets) documentation.

> If you’re using a custom Target and you’re not loading into a View
>   that would allow you to subclass ViewTarget, you’ll need to implement
>   the getSize() method.

So in your case just put the below code in `getSize` method

```
@Override
public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {
    cb.onSizeReady(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL);
}
```

Now the `onResourceReady` method will be called when you run the app.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have missed that while going through the docs